# How to get out of Outlook Folder List view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Now I can see the Calendar and Contacts in the folder list.  But I'd like to remove those and revert back to the old folder view settings.

How to get out of Outlook Folder List view?

Comment: Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this.

Comment: @CharlieRB Everything else online talks about getting into Folder List View, which is Ctrl + 6 in outlook.  I can't find any online article telling me how to revert to default.  There was a command called outlook.exe /clearview but that didn't change any sort of viewing options in the nav pane, so folder viewing still shows the calendar, contacts, tasks, etc.

Comment: `/clearview` resets views, not the navigation pane. Try using `outlook.exe /resetnavpane` to reset the navigation pane to default.

Comment: Didn't work, those are still showing and nothing's changed in the navpane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to switch back to **Mail** view.